# jquery table id and disabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've a question on using Jquery on a table.

I don't know if I'm doing it the right way and hence I ended up asking my question here after much research.

What I want is to compare the items in the variable array which holds the string converted response from JSON and if they match the list in the table, the checkbox would be disabled.

Appreciate any inputs. :)

**jQuery code**:

```
function refreshKeywords(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var refresh_form = jQuery(e.target);
    $.ajax({
        url: refresh_form.attr('action'),
        type: refresh_form.attr('method'),
        data: refresh_form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var array = $.parseJSON(response.new_list);
            alert(array);
            var html = '';
            $.each(array, function(i, item) {
                html += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
                if ($('#checkKeywords :input') == array) {
                    $('#validate').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
            $('#keywords').append(html);
            if ($('#checkKeywords :input') == array) {
                $('#validate').attr('disabled', true);
            }


        },
    });
}
```

Below is my table HTML code:

```
<table id="checkKeywords">
    <tbody>
        {% for keyword in keyword_list %}
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}<tr>{% endif %}
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" id= "validate" name="cb" value="keywords" />
              {{keyword.keyword_name}}
            </td>
            {% if forloop.counter|add:"1"|divisibleby:"3" %}</tr>{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some error comes from these lines:

```
var array = $.parseJSON(response.new_list);
```

returns a well formatted Javascript object but when you are comparing with

```
if($('#checkKeywords :input') == array){...}
```

You're comparing a set of Javascript objects with well formatted JSON parsed JS objects which are not quite compatible with the value returned from `$('#checkKeywords :input') == array`.

> If both operands are objects, they're compared as objects, and the
>   equality test is true only if both refer the same object. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

---

I would suggest to make the two objects comparable using some modification which will take the two objects and process them to return `true` or `false` according to whether the are equal.

**Update**:

In your **HTML code**

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="validate" name="cb" 
      value="{{keyword.keyword_name}}" />{{keyword.keyword_name}}
</td>
```

From your **JS**

```
...
$.each(array, function(i, item) {
    html += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
    theinputs = $('#checkKeywords :input')
    $.each(theinputs, function(i, checkbox) {
        if ($(checkbox).val() == item) {
            $(checkbox).prop('disabled', true);
            /* thanx charlietfl */
        }
    });

});
$('#keywords').append(html);
...
```

Comment: yes thanks for that bout of info but the question here is how do i do that. i'll try exploring. :)

Comment: @StanwinSiow Hope this works, i'm sorry the first time i didn't grasp what you were asking about

Comment: thanks sransara! i'll try it out and come back and accept. :D

Answer (score 2):

This should help clear up some of the issues.

```
function refreshKeywords(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var refresh_form = jQuery(e.target);

    $.ajax({
        url: refresh_form.attr('action'),
        type: refresh_form.attr('method'),
        data: refresh_form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {


            /* no need to use $.parseJSON , is handled by jQuery core*/
            //var array = $.parseJSON(response.new_list);
            var array = response.new_list;

            var html = '';
            $.each(array, function(i, item) {
                html += "<li>" + item + "</li>";

                /* was missing val() for input */
                if ($('#checkKeywords :input').val() == /*array*/ item) {

                    // use prop() method() in jQuery >= 1.6
                    /*$('#validate').attr('disabled', true);*/
                    $('#validate').prop('disabled', true)
                }
            });
            $('#keywords').append(html);

            /* duplication */
/*if($('#checkKeywords :input') == array) { $('#validate').attr('disabled', true); }*/

           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: hmm that's a pretty good analyses charlietfl but my checkboxes are still un checked. but i do like your answer. as always you are very helpful. :)

Comment: without seeing some data and more html hard to help further

Comment: oh btw the parseJson method is still needed because what comes out with out the parseJson method are all single elements. I needed the whole word

Comment: just realized checkbox issue, you can't duplicate ID's in a page so the same checkbox is being evaluated every time

Comment: is json not being sent as `application/json` ??

Comment: yea it is. but strangely enough it's not appearing on the html if i tried ur code. I have a feeling its the library itself. btw i added an alert dialog in the if loop to see if the program enters it but it's not entering.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8465/discussion-between-stanwin-siow-and-charlietfl)

Comment: use jsonlint.com to validate the json